# Why does WSDL change break vb.net application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, service, web, wsdl

I am accessing a web service that is coded in c# - I am coding my application in vb.net. The owner of the webservice made a WSDL enhancement recently by adding a few values in an enum and a few other string values to the classes that are exposed in the WSDL.

When the partner updated this WSDL my application stopped properly binding values to my objects. Portions of my objects were populated with values, but portions of the objects were not... they were NULL.

I opened the complied code and updated the web reference and the code started working again. My code is working fine but I am trying to understand why this happened. Is this some artifact of coding in VB.net or is this just something to deal with? My concern is just for future planning.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

They changed their API and broke compatibility with their old one.  The fact that they published a WSDL has made fixing the change easier on you, but once their updated web service started running, clients built from that original WSDL were going to work or not work (depending on the nature of the change).  You can take heart that this would have happened in any other language as well.  A common practice to manage this breakage is to host updated WSDLs on different URLs (usually with the version number in the URL).  This makes it easier to run different versions in parallel and not break old apps.  From time to time you will need to break your API, so having good communication with your customers is also key.  I like to make my APIs that I deprecate read only first with error messages that help a developer understand what is going on, and I fire off an email or pick up the phone as soon as I see an API call to a deprecated API.  This obviously wouldn't work for a PayPal, but if it's an option it can keep partners happy, and so far it has been worth my time.